# Сложность с определением грамматической основы

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее, основа

Помогите, пожалуйста, верно определить грамматические основы следующего предложения:
*Первым делом дедушки было построить мельницу, ибо молоть хлеб надо было ездить вёрст за сорок.*

Как понимаю я:

1) подлежащее:**построить**, сказуемое:**было делом**; 
2) подлежащее отсутствует, сказуемое: **надо было ездить**.